# How do i query Bittrex api concurrently in php

Tags: php

I have an array of altcoins i want to query using bittrex api. I loop through them and pass it on to the API as a parameter Like so:

```
$coins = array("BTC-LTC", "BTC-PTOY", "BTC-BLK");

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {  
  $mkt_code = $coins[$i];  
  getPrice($mkt_code);  
}

function getPrice($mkt_code) {  
  $uri = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market='.$mkt_code;
  $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($uri));

 /*do something like save prices in a database*/  
}
```

But if i set a cron job to run this file say every minute and array size is over 100 this could take quite a while to execute sequentially. I want a way of doing it concurrently so that i could get the prices all at once, much faster and in real time. Help please, i'm relatively new to this. Thanks

Comment: Research their API rate-limits and fair use policies. It might not be wise to do multiple requests at the same time. To the best of my knowledge, they will ban you if you do more than 1 request per second for an extended period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Guzzle's concurrent request feature](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests).